# Microsoft Excel, cannot extract the numbers of the date from a table header

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have searched similar problems but I couldn't find them. So sorry if I ask the same question. My excel table:

[image: my excel table]

This is the formula in C15:

```
=DATEDIF(B15,$C$12,"Y")
```

Using:

```
=year(B15)
```

results in "1992". However, using

```
=year(C12)
```

results in "#VALUE!"

Format cells for both of them

[image: format cells for both of them]

I have no idea where went wrong, could anyone gives me any suggestions or tips? thanks

Comment: It would be simpler if you post the file online (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Comment: shorturl.at/qxAG0

Comment: thank you for your tips, and this is the file

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the cell C12 is formatted as date with slash (`/`)
as separators.

However, your value at C12 is written as `15.09.2010`.

Setting C12 to `15/09/2010` will solve the problem.

Comment: i.e. te date is most likely "TEXT" as it is shown here *(  =TYPE(C12) yields 2 )*

Comment: @Hannu: I downloaded the worksheet - it's in date format, but has this bad value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a little more subtle than Answered so far.

It is not sufficient that a cell be formatted as the date format one desires prior to data being entered.

The data must be entered in a form that the computer's Windows settings recognize as a date (in this case) so Excel can realize it is a date and format it as such.

For instance, on my system `15/9/2010` is not a valid date. Making sure the cell formatting is `d/m/yyyy` and entering, literally, "15/9/2010" results in it being treated as text. No differently than, say, "horsey-womple" and no more successful in functions that require dates as inputs.

However, the same formatting, or formatting as `d.m.yyyy`, does yield a date when I enter the value, literally, as "9/15/2010"... It displays in the chosen format and works nicely in the date formulas.

It's fine to `display` it in **any** format you can build in Excel. But when entering it (typing, pasting, etc.), you must do so in a form that your Windows settings recognize as a date. (Changing system settings to suit the shown form would also work, though it seems unlikely you'd want to do that. And very likely that no other user would like to.)

Answer (score 0):

The value in C12 may have the 'date' format, but the value in that cell is not formatted as such (as you show in your formatting settings, the date delimiter should be a slash).

If you want the date in C12 to work you should either choose a different format for that cell (regional settings might interfere here), or reformat the value itself to use / instead of .